# Проблема с поиском максимума

Tags: c, массивы

Написал программу простейшей интерполяции. Теперь хочу задать условие "если заданная координата X для поиска значения функции не входит в интервал, то выводить определенный комментарий". Не ищется максимум
Код:

```
 #include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "windows.h"

struct point{
    double x;
    double y;
};

void printstruct(point *p, int count){
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("x = %.2lf\t",p[i].x);
        printf("y = %.2lf\n",p[i].y);
    }
}
void sortstruct(point *p, int count)
{
        for (int j=0; j<count; j++)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<count-1; i++)
            {
                if (p[i].x>p[i+1].x)
                {
                    point temp=p[i];
                    p[i]=p[i+1];
                    p[i+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        }
double findinterval(point *p, int count, double x_arg)
{
    int maxx;
    point p1, p2;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (x_arg < p[i].x)
        {
            p1 = p[i-1];
            p2 = p[i];
        }
    }
    if (x_arg < p[0].x)
    {
        printf("Координата не входит в заданный интервал\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    double yy = p1.y + ((p2.y - p1.y)/(p2.x - p1.x))*(x_arg-p1.x);
    return yy;
}
double findmax(point *p, int count, double max)
{
    max = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (p[i].x > max)
        {
            max = p[i].x;
        }
    }
    printf ("MaxX = %lf",&max);
    return max;
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    point *points;
    int n;
    printf("input count=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    points = (point*)malloc(n*sizeof(point));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Input x[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%lf", &points[i].x);
        printf("Input y[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%lf", &points[i].y);

    }
        printstruct(points, n);
        sortstruct (points, n);
        printstruct (points, n);
        findmax (points,n,0);
        double x_arg;
        printf ("Input x_arg\t ");
        scanf("%lf", &x_arg);
        printf("%.2lf\n",x_arg);
        double y_arg = findinterval(points,n,x_arg);
        printf ("y_arg = %.2lf\n", y_arg);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: `printf ("MaxX = %lf",&max);` Вы здесь хотите отобразить  адрес переменой в стеке или значение переменой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделайте проверку , на не вхождение переменой в интервал

```
if ( (x_arg < p[0].x) || (x_arg > p[count -1].x) )
{
    printf("Координата не входит в заданный интервал\n");
    exit(1);
}
```